# Does MongoDB Atlas support REST API to the database and collection

Tags: mongodb, rest, mongodb-atlas

Old MongoLab (now mLab) service provides REST APIs to databases and collections, like https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases (or https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/<dbname>/collections), etc.

Is there anything similar in MongoDB Atlas service? All API I can find is for Cluster, User, and other administration settings; not to the database itself. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Unlikely, I think: MongoDB's API interface to the data has been [deprecated for security reasons](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-mongodb-configuration/#http-interface-security) for a while now, so it would be unwise of them to open a similar API through MongoDB Atlas.

Comment: It seems possible to use the REST API over HTTPS: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB Atlas now has Data API feature in Preview
https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/api/data-api/

Answer (score 0):

They do seem to allow data interaction, judging by the blog post "How to Use MongoDB Atlas in API Integration Services" (https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/how-to-use-mongodb-atlas-in-api-integration-services).

However it is restricted to their elected third parties for integration, as stated in the same post:

> We have partnered with a number of vendors in this space to allow
>   users to take advantage of Atlas and MongoDB features from within
>   their favored development environments.

I'll stick to mLab by now.